multivariate time series forecasting
I have a dataset of 200,000 rows. Each row contains the song ID, the number of streams today (day_0), the number of streams yesterday (day_1), etc. up to the number of streams 21 days ago (day_21). My task is to predict the # of streams for the next week.
I'm trying to figure out how to structure my data to feed it into a multivariate LSTM. Currently, the window slides by one day. Is this appropriate or should I have non overlapping windows? I plan on embedding (from this post) the song ID so the LSTM can learn song-specific patterns.
Any other advice would be great!
